# Moodle: Error missingparam when call my website

Tags: php, apache, web, moodle

In CentOS 6.7 I want to try to have my web site!

in `/var`:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Aug  9  2014 account
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root   root   4096 Aug  9  2014 cache
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Feb 29 17:29 crash
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Nov 22  2013 cvs
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root   4096 Aug  9  2014 db
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root   4096 Aug  9  2014 empty
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Sep 23  2011 games
drwxr-xr-x. 32 root   root   4096 Mar  8 03:24 lib
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Sep 23  2011 local
drwxrwxr-x.  5 root   lock   4096 Mar  8 11:21 lock
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root   root   4096 Mar  8 11:21 log
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root     10 Aug  9  2014 mail -> spool/mail
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Sep 23  2011 nis
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Sep 23  2011 opt
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Sep 23  2011 preserve
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root   root   4096 Mar  8 11:23 run
drwxrwxrwx. 10 apache apache 4096 Mar  7 16:31 ScormData
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root   root   4096 Jan 31  2015 spool
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root   root   4096 Mar  8 07:53 tmp
drwxrwxrwx.  8 root   root   4096 Feb 21 15:16 www
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root   4096 Aug  9  2014 yp
```

in `www/`

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root         4096 Feb  9 20:59 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root      root         4096 Feb 18 17:47 error
drwxr-xr-x. 12 apache    apache       4096 Mar  8 11:31 html
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root      root         4096 Feb 18 17:49 icons
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root      root         4096 Mar  7 17:28 manual
drwxr-xr-x.  2 webalizer root         4096 Mar  1 03:47 usage
```

And in `html/`:
I have some files and directories with `apache` ownership.

When I want to enter `/rte/scorm/player.php` in browser this is what I have:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be missing the required parameter $scoid when accessing player.php. How are you trying to access it?

Comment: This is the way I face error: `http://mywebsite.com/rte/scorm/player.php`

Comment: And this is the path of it: `./www/html/rte/scorm/player.php`

Comment: player.php requires the $scoid parameter, so you need to access it via a url that would look something like player.php?scoid=1234.

Comment: How can specify the value `1234` ?

Comment: I've added an explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

player.php requires the `$scoid` parameter, so you need to access it via a url that would look something like `player.php?scoid=1234`

Normally you would add a SCORM resource through the admin interface to one of your courses and then the link to the SCORM will appear there. Then all you need to do is click on the link from your course; the `scoid` parameter will be part of the link.